# What is the difference between methods calls in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am learning Rust and want to understand difference between  function calls

```
    S::foo(&s); 
    T::foo(&s);
    <S as T>::foo(&s);
```

1 Why do we need all these ways? And difference?

2 Where should we use it?

```
struct S;

trait T {
    fn foo(&self);
}

impl T for S {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("XXX");        
    }
}


fn main() {
    let s = S;
    s.foo(); // (It's clear)
    S::foo(&s); 
    T::foo(&s);
    <S as T>::foo(&s);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the method syntax `s.foo()` when possible and unambiguous, it's the least verbose and applies automatic dereferencing so that your code will be cleaner.

`S::foo(&s)` is mainly useful when the `Self` type is ambiguous, it's often used with `From::from` to avoid a turbofish on `.into()` or in case of i.e. `Rc::clone` to avoid confusion if it's a cheap increase of the reference counter or more expensive clone of the inner value.

`T::foo(&s)` is necessary when both an inherent `foo` and a trait implementation exist:

```rust
// in addition to your definitions this exists
impl S {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("S")
    }
}
S::foo(&s); // -> prints S
T::foo(&s); // -> prints XXX
```

You can use the fully qualified syntax `<S as T>::foo(&s)` when you have the last two cases combined.